# Class loader error when deploying a grails war in tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, grails, deployment, classloader

I'm trying to deploy a grails app in a testing environment by running a 'grails dev war' command and manually deploying the war into a Tomcat container. The app does not run and I see several error logs like this one:

> ./logs/catalina.out:2014-01-13 09:18:53,415 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  -    Error initializing the application:
>   Error creating bean with name 'instanceTagLibraryApi': Injection of
>   autowired  dependencies failed;  nested exception is 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire method: public void
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.TagLibraryApi.setGspTagLibraryLookup(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.TagLibraryLookup);
>   nested  exception is 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'gspTagLibraryLookup': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'es.indra.nta.UiLayoutsTagLib': Initialization
>   of bean failed; nested exception is 
>   org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type
>   'org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader' to required type 
>   'groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader' for property 'classLoader'; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of
>   type   [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] to required type
>   [groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader] for property 'classLoader': no
>   matching editors or conversion strategy found

I get the same error for several beans. I'm using `Grails 2.2.2` and tried the deployment in Tomcat 5.5 and 7.0 with the same result. If I use `'grails run-app'` instead the app runs smoothly, therefore I suspect some configuration related to Tomcat is missing but don't know what and where to configure.

Any ideas about what am I missing?.

Thanks for the help!

David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem and I was wrong about my assumption of being a Tomcat configuration problem. I explain it in case anyone faces a similar problem:

In the error logs I left in the question it referred to the taglib of an in-house plugin developed by us `es.indra.nta.UiLayoutsTagLib`. Checking the taglib's code I realised that I was using the code from this SO post: [Configuration of Grails plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843216/configuration-of-grails-plugin), thus having this in my taglib's code:

```
GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader())
config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(classLoader.loadClass('MyWebServicePluginConfig'))
```

When deploying the WAR, Tomcat was using its default class loader and not finding the `GroovyClassLoader` requested by my taglib.

Removing the use of `ConfigSlurper`and using tag attributes for the config properties I was using (which additionally made more sense) removed the need for using a class loader in the taglib's code and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when I upgraded to grails 2.2.x (from 1.3.7)

In `application.properties`, I had

```
plugins.tomcat=2.2.x
```

and I had to delete it and add in `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy` :

```
plugins {
    build ':tomcat:2.2.x'
}
```

It solved my issue, I hope it solves yours also.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Isammoc. Unfortunately the configuration is already like that. I have `plugins { build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion" }` in my BuildConfig.groovy and no `plugins.tomcat` reference in my application.properties.